# Selenium drop down issue in java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a website which i am trying to automate i am able to login and click one of the menu, but i am facing problem when i have click third child

say i have a mainmenu which displalys submenu , onclick of the submenu it displaly third menu which has 10 links displayed in top-down order i have click on 9th child which i am unable to do.

Below is the code:

```
WebElement myElement1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/ul/li/ul/li[2]/span/span/span"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(myElement1).build().perform();
myElement1.click();

WebElement myElement2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/ul/li/ul/li[2]/ul/li/span/span/span"));
Actions builder1 = new Actions(driver);
builder1.moveToElement(myElement2).build().perform();
myElement2.click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/ul/li/ul/li[2]/ul/li/ul/li[9]/a/span/span"));
System.out.println(ele.getText());

WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/ul/li/ul/li[2]/ul/li/ul/li[9]/a/span/span")));
System.out.println(" about to get enter time sheet" + element.getText());
System.out.println(isElementPresent(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/ul/li/ul/li[2]/ul/li/ul/li[9]/a/span/span")));
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2500, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
org.openqa.selenium.Point coordinates = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/ul/li/ul/li[2]/ul/li/ul/li[9]/a/span/span")).getLocation();
System.out.println(coordinates.getX() + " " + coordinates.getY());
WebElement myElement3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/ul/li/ul/li[2]/ul/li/ul/li[9]/a/span/span"));
Actions builder3 = new Actions(driver);
builder3.moveToElement(myElement3).build().perform();
myElement3.click();
```

The last dropdown is where it fails.

Comment: Note that you do not need to start from the very top of the tree, i.e you don't have to start at `html` and work your way through the HTML until you get to your element. Also your XPath is based a lot on the position of elements, this could be half the problem.

Comment: unfortunetly i have only 500 chars i cant paste whole thing so part of  code is in the below comment,

Comment: <li class="static dynamic-children" _events="[object Object]" hoverDebouncer="0">
<SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN >Request /Approvals</SPAN></SPAN></SPAN>
<UL class=dynamic>
<LI class="dynamic dynamic-children" hoverDebouncer="0"><SPAN ><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Request </SPAN></SPAN></SPAN>
<UL >
<LI ><A  href="/BusinessCard"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>DUmmy</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
<LI ><A  href="/LeaveRequest"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Apply Leave</SPAN></SPAN>

Comment: complete xpath should not be problem lets say when i am running this on same browser  correct me if i am wrong

Comment: No, you are right, it probably isn't, but it was more a tip. You can edit your question to put your HTML in, don't post it in the comments.

Comment: i used <pre><code> place my html</pre></code> but still it rendered as html when i tried adding html code in my question

Comment: Yeah that's the problem, there are no tags to use when inputting code. Just take all your HTML, indent it by 4 spaces or 1 single tab, and this will create a code block. Do not use `pre` or `code`.

Answer (score 0):

there was similar kind of bug submitted for selenium 2.0 and has been closed. Please refer to the latest stable build of selenium.

Let's refer to the below menu drop down menu with 2 levels.

```
Menu
  Item 1
      SubItem1
      SubItem2
  Item 2
```

i would suggest the 2 approaches for this problem

***Approach 1:*** from your above code i see there are click events defined for Level1 Menu item and also to Level2 Menu Items. Instead directly refer Level 2 items without clicking Level 1 items as shown below:

```
Menu.click();
Actions Build = new Actions(driver);
Build.moveToElement(Menu).moveToElement(Item1).moveToElement(SubItem2).click().build().perform();
```

***Approach 2*** The JavaScript way, though it's a safe work around to click on Menu Items on Page.

```
js.ExecuteScript("return $(\"a:contains('Menu')\").mouseover();");
js.ExecuteScript("return $(\"a:contains('Item1')\").next(':eq(1)').mouseover();");
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("SubItem2")).Click();
```

Here is an live example with Approach 1... (C# code snippet & Amazon website)

```
        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/ref=cs_top_nav_gb27");
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        IWebElement Menu = driver.FindElement(By.Id("nav-bar-inner")).FindElement(By.Id("nav-shop-all-button"));
        Menu.Click();

        IWebElement Item1 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("nav_cat_4"));
        Actions Build = new Actions(driver);
        Build.MoveToElement(Menu).MoveToElement(Item1).Click().Build().Perform();

        IWebElement SubItem = driver.FindElement(By.Id("nav_subcats_4")).FindElement(By.LinkText("Games"));
        Build.MoveToElement(Menu).MoveToElement(Item1).MoveToElement(SubItem).Click().Build().Perform();
```

Here is example of Amazon Site, where initially it clicks on Top Menu first and then it clicks of the Item1 (level1) and then on it clicks on Item2 via Level1 via TopMenu

i hope this helps....All the best :)

Comment: a:contains('Menu') does it look into anchor tag sorry i am not getting this can you explain more. IN My case they are li and span tag <li class="static dynamic-children" _events="[object Object]" hoverDebouncer="0"> <SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN >Request /Approvals</SPAN>    I click Request/Approvals

Comment: Yes buddy...it does look into Anchor tags. In your case you are using "***li***" for ordering but internally your code too has Anchor tags for references. So it should work with your HTML code as well.
<A href="/BusinessCard">
<SPAN class=additional-background>
<SPAN class=menu-item-text>Dummy</SPAN>
</SPAN>
</A>

Comment: THe third mouse over is not actually clicking it or submitting the form

Comment: Referring to 2nd approach...Did you mean the third line which clicks on the SubItem2??? or the second line ???

Comment: river.FindElement(By.LinkText("SubItem2")).Click(); this is actullay were is not working

Comment: I have added an working example of Amazon Website....with ***Approach 1***..its working. Please check and do let me know...All the best

Comment: well i had same code earlier too but in java it gives me                       \org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Given coordinates (-10575, 58) are outside the document. Error: [MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError] The target location (-10575, 58) is not on the webpage.
Command duration or timeout: 47 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:09:54'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: